# Read rgba8 from SSBO

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I need to pass ~ 1 Mb of 1D image data (rgba8) to compute shader. I tried that with 2D texture and everything is ok.

Now I'm interesting in how to achieve that with SSBO.
I can pass any data as void* with `glBufferData`.
But how to read pixels from that SSBO in shader as `vec4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to unpack the data manually.

You have to read a pixel of the data as a `uint` (which is a 32-bit unsigned integer). Then you have to use bit manipulation to unpack the 4 8-bit components from that data. Then normalize it back into 4 floats.

Fortunately, GLSL has the `unpackUnorm4x8` function, which does exactly this. It takes a `uint` and spits out a `vec4`.